# How to sort a list of dictionaries based on two different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list containing dictionaries similar to the below example. I want to try and sort the list using tbl_nm and seq. Not sure how to make it happen.
Example List with Dictionaries

```
[
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 3, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 2", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 2", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 3", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 4", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 4", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"}
]
```

Expected Output:-

```
[
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 3, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 2", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 2", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 3", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 4", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
    {"tbl_nm": "Table 4", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"}
]
```

Comment: @Itworksonmypc Perhaps because "there is no effort shown by the OP" thing, although I don't get the point to be honest, except when the question is obviously a homework assignment.

Comment: This is true. There is both Python and pythkn 3 tagged in the question, yet there is no Python code to speak of, which is troubling to say the least. I agree question might be legit though, however lack of effort sways me from upvoting this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.sort()`, passing in a lambda function as the `key` parameter. The key is a tuple with `tbl_nm` as the first element, and `seq` as the second element. This means we sort on `tbl_nm` first, then use `seq` if two dictionaries have the same `tbl_nm` value.

```py
data.sort(key=lambda x: (x["tbl_nm"], x["seq"]))
print(data)
```